# TypeError for openlayers3 measure example of area

Tags: openlayers, css, typeerror

I have got the typeerror for the 
1. TypeError: helpTooltipElementa is undefined
2. helpTooltipElementa.innerHTML = helpMsga;

### I have defined the helpTooltipElementa in the code even though i am getting this error repeatedly can any one suggest the required modifications please code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Measure example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="ol.js"></script>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tooltip-measure {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tooltip-static {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.tooltip-measure:before,
.tooltip-static:before {
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  left: 50%;
}
.tooltip-static:before {
  border-top-color: #ffcc33;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button  id="but1"  value="area" onclick=addInteractionarea();><img src="area.png"></button>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>
var mapview = new ol.View({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          center: [79.419,15.428],
          zoom: 8
        });
var vectorsource = new ol.source.Vector();
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorsource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#ffcc33',
      width: 2
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33'
      })
    })
  })
});
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'India',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://172.31.4.37/geoserver/ndem50k/wms',
              params: {LAYERS: 'ndem50k:apstateadmin50nrsc2014'}
            }),
            transparent: false
          });

var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [layer1,vector],
             controls: ol.control.defaults({
          zoom: false,
          attribution: false,
          rotate: false
        }),
            view: mapview
        });

var sketcha;var helpTooltipElementa;var helpTooltipa;var measureTooltipElementa;var measureTooltipa;var continuePolygonMsga = 'Click to continue drawing the polygon';


var pointerMoveHandlera = function(evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
var helpMsga = 'Click to start drawing';
var tooltipCoorda= evt.coordinate;

  if (sketcha) {
    var outputa;
    var geoma = (sketcha.getGeometry());
      outputa= formatArea((geoma));
      helpMsga = continuePolygonMsga;
      tooltipCoorda = geoma.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();    
        measureTooltipElementa.innerHTML = outputa;
        measureTooltipa.setPosition(tooltipCoorda);
    }

  helpTooltipElementa.innerHTML = helpMsga;
  helpTooltipa.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
};

map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandlera);

var drawa; 
function addInteractionarea() {

  drawa = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: vectorsource,
    type: 'Polygon',
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        lineDash: [10, 10],
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        })
      })
    })
  });
  map.addInteraction(drawa);

  createMeasureTooltipa();
  createHelpTooltipa();

  drawa.on('drawstart',
      function(evt) {

        sketcha = evt.feature;
      }, this);

  drawa.on('drawend',
      function(evt) {
        measureTooltipElementa.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
        measureTooltipa.setOffset([0, -7]);
        sketcha = null;
        measureTooltipElementa = null;
        createMeasureTooltipa();
      }, this);
}

function createHelpTooltipa() {
  if (helpTooltipElementa) {
    helpTooltipElementa.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElementa);
  }
  helpTooltipElementa = document.createElement('div');
  helpTooltipElementa.className = 'tooltip';
  helpTooltipa = new ol.Overlay({
    element: helpTooltipElementa,
    offset: [15, 0],
    positioning: 'center-left'
  });
  map.addOverlay(helpTooltipa);
}

function createMeasureTooltipa() {
  if (measureTooltipElementa) {
    measureTooltipElementa.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElementa);
  }
  measureTooltipElementa = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElementa.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltipa = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElementa,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltipa);
}
var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
var formatArea = function(polygon) {
  var area;


          var sourceProja = map.getView().getProjection();
          var geoma = (polygon.clone().transform(
              sourceProja, 'EPSG:4326'));
          var coordinates = geoma.getLinearRing(0).getCoordinates();
          area = Math.abs(wgs84Sphere.geodesicArea(coordinates));
    ;
  var outputa;
  if (area > 10000) {
    outputa = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
  } else {
    outputa = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
  }
  return outputa;
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

error on the line line110 :  helpTooltipElementa.innerHTML = helpMsga;
but i define the variable var helpTooltipElementa;

Answer (score 1):

I think that it has something to do with the fact that `helpTooltipElementa` isn't a DOM so that you can change its `innerHTML`

you can add this :

```
var helpTooltipElementa = document.createElement('div');
```

to create an element and then change it's innerHTML

Comment: didnt get your point sir

Comment: helpTooltipElement a is an html element that appears on the map, in this function var pointerMoveHandlera = function(evt) {...} you seem to use it before declaring it s an html element. try addind the code in my answer when you declare helpTooltipElementa as a global variable

Comment: i have declared it globally only

Comment: Yes but you didn't add the document.createElement line then. This too should be in its global declaration

Comment: so then i need to add this lines in html ? measureTooltipElementa = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElementa.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltipa = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElementa,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'

Comment: after this line in your js code : var sketcha;var helpTooltipElementa;var helpTooltipa;var measureTooltipElementa;var measureTooltipa;var continuePolygonMsga = 'Click to continue drawing the polygon';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42942/discussion-between-user28536-and-hicham-zouarhi).